# How to Count Unique record for defaultdict in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fresher in Python3 and now stuck in one problem.

Problem Statement: I have a defaultdict which have multiple values for one single key. In those multiple values, there are similar and different values.

Now, I would like to get a summary(number of count based on unique records ) for each key.

dictionary (named as "d") as below defaultdict(, {'0': ['"126"},', '"115"},', '"60"},'], '1': ['"126"},'], '2': ['"126"},', '"126"},', '"126"},', '"148"},', '"99"},'], '3': ['"126"},', '"226"},'], '4': ['"126"},', '"90"},'], })

Expected Output:

```
0: countALL :3; 1: countALL :1; 2: countALL :3; 3: countALL :2; 4: countALL :2;
```

Like for example, For key '2', there are 3 records of 126, 1 of 148 and 1 of 99. So summary would be 3 since there are three types of unique records.

This is for Python3 program for my research which I am using to distinguish different type traffic coming from net.

Expected Result:

```
0: countALL :3; 1: countALL :1; 2: countALL :3; 3: countALL :2; 4: countALL :2;
```

Comment: try with this instead
`counts = {k: len(v) for k, v in d.items()}`

Comment: Can you clean up your inputs and outputs? Initially you mention having a defaultdict which you need to perform counting operations on but then in your code example you use a set. The code example shouldn't be printing `countAll` anywhere but you suggest it does.

Comment: Damiano C., your solution was also worked. there were a slight differences from what I was expecting. your code was giving the total count based in records but I was expecting to get only the count based on different value/records only. Just close to the expected. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer to my interpretation of your question, though my interpretation might be incorrect.

```
from collections import Counter

data = {1: [2,3,4,3,4], 2: [6,5,3,5]}

for key, values in data.items():
    print(f'{key} has the following unique counts {Counter(values)}')
```

which outputs the following:

```
1 has the following unique counts Counter({3: 2, 4: 2, 2: 1})
2 has the following unique counts Counter({5: 2, 6: 1, 3: 1})
```

Comment: The output is giving the details correctly. But what I need is to get the count of unique items. i.e.                                                                                                                   1 has the following type of unique counts  Counter (3)

Comment: Ah, in that case you can do `print(f'{key} has {len(Counter(values))} unique items')`. If you find this answer helpful don't forget to upvote/mark as solution.

Comment: Yeah, that perfectly worked and got what I exactly wanted. Thank you for your Great support.